# Can not import Google play service 7.0.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to upgrade play service from 6.5.87 to 7.0.0.

I am getting `Error:Execution failed for task` when i deploy that app on device.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Here is my build.gradle

https://gist.github.com/melody-dev/7c72db4aca8c2083a067

Comment: do you get more output? try to run the gradle build with stacktrace mode

Comment: @A.S. this is output from stacktrace mode >> [gist link](https://gist.github.com/melody-dev/c3245c1386ad2d7cffb3)

Comment: Improved the readability by reforming sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following and it would work

1.click on the build menu button and clean the project.
2. After that rebuild the project from same menu by clicking rebuild button.

This would resolve the issue if not then open sdk manager and in extras check whether Google play services is installed or not if not install one.

Comment: I already try but still have same an error while deploy to device.

Comment: this is full error log with stacktrace mode >>> [Full error log](https://gist.github.com/melody-dev/07cd195bf87609844b16)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. It is because of conflicts of Google libraries in your project. You've added a new one, but did not delete the old one.
Try these steps:

1. Clean your project
2. Rebuild project
3. Restart Android Studio