# Cannot start my application after a android studio update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After a android studio update I can't start my application anymore. Everytime I'm getting this err:

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I tried these solutions:

[Android Studio : com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518323/android-studio-com-android-ide-common-process-processexception)

[Can not import Google play service 7.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538845/can-not-import-google-play-service-7-0-0)

Still the same error. Anybody knows what I can do?

Comment: I think the problem is using java 7 ,upgrade your jdk to version 8

Comment: Done, nothing happens... Same Error, just with "jdk1.8.0_51.jdk" instead of 1.7... Any other idea?

Comment: I really don't have any suggestion more but it seems this is a common error have you looked at these?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640314/android-studio-fails-to-debug-with-error-org-gradle-process-internal-execexcepti

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821614/android-studio-error-org-gradle-process-internal-execexception

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle

Comment: defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

worked for me! thanks @sadeghsaati

Answer (score 0):

Answer in the comments above! This worked for me:

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```